# Strapi is only showing Content ID instead of Content name

Tags: strapi

Strapi is showing only the ID in a relation content type. I want to see the postalCode instead of the ID. What do I have to change/edit so that Strapi is showing me the postalCodes which I already entered instead of the IDs?

[image: Strapi Content]

Answer (score 3):

The option you are searching for is hided by the dropdown ;)

1. Select "Configure the view" or "Anzeige konfigurieren"
   [image]
2. On the presented Screen you can then see under "Relational fields" your relations. Hover over the field you want to edit the display name and select it.
   [image]
3. In the opened Modal window you can select the Attribute you want to use (highlighted in the screenshot)...
   [image]